# How fix this error : exchangelib.errors.InvalidTypeError: 'tzinfo' <UTC> must be of type <class 'exchangelib.ewsdatetime.EWSTimeZone'>

Tags: python, django, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

In my Django project, I have bump the Exchangelib version (3.2.1 to 4.9.0) and now an error occurs.
Traceback :

```
  File "/home/.../workspace/my_project/exchange_manager/models.py", line 297, in create_event
    event = self.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1409, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1352, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1353, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1353, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1294, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 842, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1428, in get_db_prep_value
    return connection.ops.adapt_datetimefield_value(value)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 247, in adapt_datetimefield_value
    value = timezone.make_naive(value, self.connection.timezone)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 256, in make_naive
    return value.astimezone(timezone).replace(tzinfo=None)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exchangelib/ewsdatetime.py", line 128, in astimezone
    t = super().astimezone(tz=tz).replace(tzinfo=tz)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 228, in fromutc
    return super(utc.__class__, self).fromutc(dt)
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-iOt348t5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exchangelib/ewsdatetime.py", line 93, in __new__
    raise InvalidTypeError("tzinfo", tzinfo, EWSTimeZone)
exchangelib.errors.InvalidTypeError: 'tzinfo' <UTC> must be of type <class 'exchangelib.ewsdatetime.EWSTimeZone'>
```

Before the call of the create method, I use this code to transform timestamp to EWSDateTime instance.

```
LOCAL_TZ = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
def timestamp_to_ews_datetime(timestamp):
    """
    Transform timestamp to EWSDateTime instance
    :param timestamp:
    :return:
    """
    temp_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000.0)
    temp_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(temp_datetime, is_dst=None).astimezone(LOCAL_TZ)
    return EWSDateTime.from_datetime(temp_datetime)
```

I have edit the LOCAL_TZ value but it does not works :

```
LOCAL_TZ = EWSTimeZone('Europe/Paris')
```

I don't now if the problem is in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thwas was answered in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/1140#issuecomment-1308814613:

When you're trying to save an `EWSDateTime` to the database, the `sqlite3` package is localizing datetime values to UTC and then removing the timezone info. `EWSDateTime` instances does not allow removing timezone info.

When you set the value on a Django model field, you should use a plain `datetime` object. The easiest way to convert from `EWSDateTime` to `datetime` is probably:

```py
>>> from exchangelib import EWSDateTime, EWSTimeZone
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = EWSDateTime(2013, 2, 1, tzinfo=EWSTimeZone.localzone())
>>> datetime(*d.timetuple()[:6], tzinfo=d.tzinfo)
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=EWSTimeZone(key='Europe/Copenhagen'))
```